# displays coordinates rather Label as I want

Tags: questionnaire

Hi there I am MSc student and i am new to LaTeX. I wrote a program that shows 
coordinate in display rather label as I want like this display [image].

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}



        \foreach  \Point/\PointLabel  in {(0,0), (-0.08,-0.75), (-0.22,-1.5), (-0.44,-2.25), (-1.01,-3.5), (-1.49,-4.25), (-2.09,-5), (-2.87,-5.75)/,}
        \draw[thick, fill=black] \Point circle (0.08) node[below right] {$\PointLabel$};


            \draw[thick, black] (0,0.4) arc (0:-52:8cm);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

still have a problem, help me if there is a configuration problem

Comment: Sir thanks but still there is a problem with me , may be configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's MWE, no labels were provided, so I added them to the `\foreach` data list.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}



        \foreach  \Point/\PointLabel  in {(0,0)/B=P_n, (-0.08,-0.75)/P_{a=1},
         (-0.22,-1.5)/P_k, (-0.44,-2.25)/Q_k, (-1.01,-3.5)/P_{k-1},
         (-1.49,-4.25)/P_2, (-2.09,-5)/P_1, (-2.87,-5.75)/A=P_0,}
        \draw[thick, fill=black] \Point circle (0.08) node[below right] {$\PointLabel$};


            \draw[thick, black] (0,0.4) arc (0:-52:8cm);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir thanks but still there is a problem with me , may be configuration problem. I copied your code but not showing Labels but still shows coordinates

Comment: @FaizaNiaz Unfortunately, I cannot recreate your problem.